# How to know if a ListView item uses two lines?

Tags: java, android, listview

I know we don't have to do that, but I use a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`, so the ListView isn't scrollable.
I found some functions that calculate the height of the listview according to the number of items and it works well.

I first used this one:

```
private static void expandListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    if (listAdapter == null)
        return;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    listView.measure(0, 0);
    params.height = listView.getMeasuredHeight() * listAdapter.getCount() + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

And then this one:

```
private static void expandListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

I don't understand all of this but it works only if there is one line for each item.
So if I use a small screen and an item takes two lines of text, I won't see the last element of the list.
I searched how to know if a ListItem takes two lines but I don't find anything, and the method `getMeasuredHeight()` returns the height of a single line item.

Is there a way to do what I want to do? I don't want to just add 50 to the height if the string exceed X caracters. I'd like something that'll work on all device size.

Comment: `but I use a ListView inside a ScrollView` why are you not using a NestedScrollView?

Comment: I tried but it didn't change anything.

Comment: use recyclerview instead of list view and use NestedScrollView in instead of ScrollView, that best for you

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get the number of lines in the `textView` instead of the number of lines of the item itself by using:
    textview.getLineCount()

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution about my problem.
I call the method that calculates the height of the ListView in the Override method `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    expandListViewHeight(listView);
}
```

There is the `MenuInflater` parameter because my class extends `Fragment`. And in the `onCreateView` I added the line

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

So I didn't need to edit the `expandListViewHeight` method.